# Creating define header file with auto value increment

Tags: c++, qt

This is the output that I would like to achieve.

```
#define car 1 
#define bus 2 
#define taxi 3
```

... and so on.

Is it possible such that if I add one ANYWHERE it will auto help me generate the number example 4 (meaning taking the largest number + 1), but if I remove one from the middle example #define bus 2, the numbering will all remain. How to create such define header file?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in C++ itself to do what you're asking for.

The obvious choices would be to create a small tool of your own to handle the job, or use something like a C++ enum instead, so you'd get something like:

```
enum {car=1, bus, taxi};
```

In this case, adding items to the end would be trivial:

```
enum {car = 1, bus, taxi, airplane};
```

...but removing an item from the middle would require a little extra work:

```
enum { car = 1, bus, airplane = 4};
```

That is to say, anywhere you want a number skipped, you need to specify the value you want assigned to the next item after the number you're skipping (anywhere you don't specify otherwise, each symbol be given a value one greater than its predecessor).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a small util written in python that we also use in our buildsystem for such things. It serves as a **pre-preprocessor**. Those are things that have to be done before the preprocessor as it cannot be done with C++.

## Dedicated tool

#### main.py

```
# 1. Add items wherever you wish to extend
# 2. a. Set None for removed items
# 2. b. Do not add None if you want it all incremental (should be default)

mylist = ('car', 'bus', None, 'taxi')
with open('myheader.h', 'w') as f:
    for index, item in enumerate(mylist, 1):
        if item:
            f.write('#define %s %s\n' % (item, index))
```

You could even make it less comprehensive for an average C++ programmer if you want to make it more pythonic. You would use python comprehension then, but it outputs the same.

```
mylist = ('car', 'bus', None, 'taxi')
with open('myheader.h', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('#define %s %s\n' % (item, index)) for index, item in enumerate(mylist, 1) if item]
```

#### Run it

```
python main.py
```

#### Output file

```
#define car 1
#define bus 2
#define taxi 4
```

You would then invoke this python script in your buildsystem before trying to compile your source. We do that in a large project and it works quite OK. You need to have python as a dependency, but it is available nearly everywhere these days anyhow.

## C++ enum

Of course, the best would be in this case to use C++ enums as follows:

```
class enum Items
{
    car = 1,
    bus,
    taxi
};
```

Do not forget to use the new class enums should you be able to use at least C++11.

They have various advantages over the older style. Anyway, the good thing about enum is that it will increment the value automatically for you by one starting from zero by default. That is also why you need to explicitly make it start from one as desired in your question.

However, since your question seems to be tagged with `Qt`, too, I will let you know that there is also a [Q_ENUMS](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS) macro that you could look into to extend your vision about enums in Qt.

In addition, if you remove a value in the middle, then you will need to tag the one after the removed with the "original" value as enum will "recount" the values for you.

However, you need to revisit whether it makes sense to remove an enum value at all. If it is a library, it would go as a source incompatible change which you really should not do so often. Now and again when you do it, it is acceptable to reorder manually since such a change should be considered rare anyway, so it may not be worth the automation for this corner case at all.